# Unity 2D. Ортографическая камера выводит изображение в виде квадрата в угол экрана

Tags: c#, unity3d, камера

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: камера выводит изображение только в углу экрана. Изначальная задумка представляет собой рендеринг 1 комнаты. При входе в дверь координаты камеры просто изменяются на 10f. В чем обстоит вопрос: есть ли возможность растянуть камеру на весь экран, в прямоугольную область? Какие есть радикальные методы решения? Быть может в крайнем случае перестроить задумку проекта? Касаемо настроек камеры, все свойства менял, максимум, чего удалось добиться, это расширить камеру, но тогда она заходит уже на соседние комнаты, что категорически не нужно. При изменении параметров Viewport Rect по Y, H, камера тоже расширяется.
3 скриншот - как камера выглядит изначально. 2 скриншот - как камера выглядит после расширения. 1 скриншот - вид из редактора.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Не пишите дополнительную информацию в комментариях, вопрос можно редактировать, а комментарий удалите. Приложите текстом код, относящийся к вопросу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете попробовать сделать вторую камеру с настройкой Clear Flags - Depth Only,
далее настроить слой Culling Mask на конкретный тайл комнаты или включить туда разные маски(предметы, оружие, персонажа). Далее вы можете центрировать камеру прямо над тайлом со своими параметрами. Так же вы можете попробовать использовать глубину(Depth) для того, чтобы вывести ваше изображение с ортогональной камеры поверх остальных. Чтобы создать подложку задник для перекрытия всего лишнего, внутри камеры вы можете создать новый Canvas, внутри которого создать Image, растянутый на всю ширину холста.В Canvas необходимо выставить Render Mode на Screen Space-Camera и поиграть со значением Plane Distance чтобы добиться отсечения всего лишнего.
Это точно должно помочь вам)